# Linq with expect: Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I have this exeption: Unable to create a constant value of type ....ViewModels.Yarn.FilterNameDto'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

ViewModels:

```
public class YarnListViewModel
{
    public YarnListFilter YarnListFilter { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FilterNameDto> FilterNames { get; set; }
}

public class YarnListFilter
{
    public int? BrandId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class FilterNameDto
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

In Contoller:

```
List<FilterNameDto> nlnames = new List<FilterNameDto>
{
    new FilterNameDto { ProductName = "Farouche" },
    new FilterNameDto { ProductName = "La Parisienne" },
...
};

var filternamesdb = _context.YarnFullAdmins
                    .Where(n => n.ProductName != null)
                    .GroupBy(n => n.ProductName)
                    .Select(n => n.FirstOrDefault());
if (yarnListFilter.BrandId > 0)
    filternamesdb = filternamesdb.Where(b => b.BrandId == yarnListFilter.BrandId);

// Until here everything works fine

var filternamesdblist = filternamesdb.Select(n => new FilterNameDto
    {
        ProductName = n.ProductName,
    }).Except(nlnames).ToList(); // I remove the names who are in the nlnames list

nlnames.AddRange(filternamesdblist); // And I add them so they come out first

var filternames = filternamesdblist;
if (yarnListFilter.BrandId == null || yarnListFilter.BrandId == 1)
    filternames = nlnames;

var viewModel = new YarnListViewModel
{
FilterNames = filternames
};

    return View(viewModel);
```

.Exept is my problem!

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.YarnListFilter.ProductName
, new SelectList(Model.FilterNames, "ProductName", "ProductName")
,"Filter by Name"
, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

My goal is to have some of the items (referenced in nlnames List) who are actually in the query result (everywhere in this list) to come out first. So, I thought I remove them from the list and then add them so they are first listed.
Or is there (and I'm sure there is) a much better way to achieve this?!?!?

To resume it clear and short:
The database returns Aaa, Bbb, Ccc, Ddd, Eee
And I want Bbb, Ddd to be first!
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your object `nlnames` can't be translated into something which SQL Server understands. In order to get around this you could call `.ToList()` before the `.Except()`

```
var filternamesdblist = filternamesdb
    .Select(n => new FilterNameDto
    {
        ProductName = n.ProductName,
    })
    .ToList()
    .Where(n => !nlnames.Any(nl => nl.ProductName == n.ProductName))
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you could change the type of `nlnames` to `List<string>` which can be understood by SQL Server:

```
var nlnames = new List<string> { "Farouche", "La Parisienne" };

var filternamesdblist = filternamesdb
    .Where(n => !nlnames.Contains(n.ProductName))
    .Select(n => new FilterNameDto
    {
        ProductName = n.ProductName,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam. No exeption. But it did not remove the names from the list. So now I have them 2 times! Any idea?

Comment: I think that will be an issue with the `.Except()`, maybe try replacing it with `.Where(n => !nlnames.Any(nl => nl.ProductName == n.ProductName))`. The except will probably be expecting the object to be equal, which yours won't be as `filternamesdb` comes from the DB and  `nlnames` is a hardcoded list

Comment: No, sorry. With this one, I'm back to my exception

Comment: Are you calling `.ToList()` before that `.Where(...` condition? I've edited my answer to reflect this change

Comment: No after. I will try before!

Comment: Calling `.ToList()` before using `nlnames` is required in order to prevent that exception from being thrown

Comment: That's it. Calling .ToList() and then .Where works perfectly. Thank you so so much @Adam. Have a great day.